# After consolidating 3 different alfresco application, OOTB search is not working

Tags: solr, alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

I have consolidated 3 different alfresco application, initially we have 3 separate applications in alfresco.

but now we have consolidated those 3 applications and all applications repository layer code is running on single instance and there are 3 different share instances.

But here alfresco OOTB search functionality is not working properly.
I also found the root cause that all 3 applications are having `search.get.js` file

but for all these application we have some custom code in each file.

so can anyone please suggest me the way to use all 3 search.get.js files to achieve search functionality.

Comment: How exactly did you consolidate 3 different applications?

Comment: @Lista ......................... 
3 repository side amp we have consolidated and the are running on single instance, and for those 3 application we have 3 separate share instances.